# Trying to get Hobbit clients to show cpu, mem, disk, etc

Tags: monitoring

I have a Hobbit server set up with a handful of hosts using conn, http, ssh, and sslcert services, but would like to add the other tests as well. I've installed hobbit-client on a server, and added:

```
 # CLIENT:fqdn.example.com
```

to it's host line in bb-hosts, and added:

```
HOST=fqdn.example.com
```

before the default configuration in hobbit-clinets.cfg, but no joy. Does anyone know what else I need to do for those tests to register?

Answer (score 1):

Your changes to bb-hosts and hobbit-clients.cfg should not be necessary. The following entry in bb-hosts works fine for me:

```
10.0.0.10    myserver
```

And the extra columns will show regardless of your hobbit-clients.cfg configuration.

I would check the client side:

- In hobbitclient.cfg, is the BBDISP variable set to the IP address of the server?
- Have you run runclient.sh on the client? You should add it as a service so it starts automatically when the host starts.
- Do the clientlaunch.log and hobbitclient.log show errors?

If that doesn't work, make sure hobbitd is running on the server and listening on the port defined in hobbitclient.cfg.

Comment: At first, the /var/run/hobbit directory didn't exist; I found a bug on launchpad that noted this ( https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hobbit/+bug/235137). However, this threw other errors about not being able to chmod. After creating the directory and relaunching, I found a bbdisp-runtime.cfg with 127.0.0.1 as the server. I replaced that and restarted, only to have my ip overwritten again by the 127.0.0.1. I then changed it again, without restarting the client. Now there are no error messages in the client, and no status on the server.

Comment: Also, the server does show that it is listening:  hobbitd    1051    hobbit    3u     IPv4               8012      0t0        TCP *:1984 (LISTEN)

Comment: UPDATE: I tried installing it on another (newer) machine; it shows the correct address, but there are no entries in the logs on either the server or the client, in spite of the hobbit daemon running.

Comment: When you run the client, it should at least create some entries in the clientlaunch.log file: "hobbitlaunch starting" and "Loading tasklist configuration.."

Answer (score 0):

I had the same behaviour when I needed to change the server the client was reporting to.

On Debian, I found that the file `/etc/default/hobbit-client` was actually providing the IP address.

I tracked this down when I saw it was an included file in `/etc/hobbit/hobbitclient.cfg`.